# Actionbar home backbutton drawable selector

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to have selector state for up-button(<) by

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/action_bar_home_as_up_indicator</item>
```

in the styles. where action_bar_home_as_up_indicator is a drawable xml with selector states pressed and default,
but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to add android namespace try

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/action_bar_home_as_up_indicator</item>
```